# Fazer redirecionamento atravez de htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

Fiz a migração de um site para outro servidor.
No servidor atual, todos os posts do site tinha um index.php no link
www.MEUSITE.com.br/index.php/teste

no novo servidor eu quero quer fique
www.MEUSITE.com.br/teste

tem como fazer isso por **.htaccess** ou PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poderia fazer assim :

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$  /$1  [L,R=301]
```

Redirecione a url que contenha após o domínio **index.php** escapando o ponto com barra invertida, precedido de / (**barra**), e um conjunto de caracteres delimitado na minha expressão por : **(.*)**

**ou**

também poderia montar dessa forma, aonde está (.*) colocar assim:

```
([a-z0-9_\-]+)
```

mas só funciona com os caracteres demarcados na expressão que são **a** até **z** números de **0** até **9** o carácter **underline** e o **traço**, que no caso por se tratar de carácter especial utilizamos uma barra invertida antes para escapa-lo, poderia adaptar as suas necessidades.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/([a-z0-9_\-]+)$  /$1  [L,R=301]
```

O **[+]**  indica que pode ser, um ou uma combinação de caracteres da expressão.

O **[L]** é last, ou seja, em uma lista de condições, não serão lidas as condições abaixo da que estiver com esta flag.

O **[R]** é redirect, isso comanda o navegador a fazer o redirecionamento É preciso colocar a URL completa.

> No seu caso estou usando o **HTTP STATUS** 301 para levar a relevância da url nas serps para a nova url.

Acredito que a expressão esteja correta. **Não realizei testes**, espero que seja útil, abraços.